# How to read the following code for main? I do not know this

Tags: c++

How to read the following code for main?
I do not know this

Code :

```
class one
{
public:
    void operator()() const
    {
        f();
        f1();
    }
};
```

I want to call the operator To main?

Answer (score 2):

`void operator()() const` defines a [function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other), which can be used as:

```
    one ob;

    ob(); // calls ob.operator()()
```

For another, more complete, example.

```
#include <iostream>

class Two
{
public:
    int operator()(const char *str) const
    {
        std::cout << "operator() called with " << str << std::endl;
        return 101;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Two two;
    int n = two("'test'");
    std::cout << "operator() returned " << n << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
operator() called with 'test'
operator() returned 101
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of the class in the main function and call the function using that instance.

```
class one
{
public:
    void operator()() const
    {
        f();
        f1();
    }
};

int main() {
one obj_one;

// calling the member function -> method
obj_one.operator()();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `obj_one.operator();` That should be `obj_one.operator()();` instead.

Comment: `obj_one();` ought to be enough. Come to think of it, that's kind of the point of the `()` operator. You can call the instance as a function.